# Galleria auto slideshow

Tags: javascript, slideshow, galleria

Creating a slideshow using Galleria.io APIs.
Galleria's DIV tag in my HTML page looks like :

```
   <div class="content">
      <div id="galleria">
        <!-- I have used Javascript to input values in this DIV tag -->
      </div>

      <div id="full" style="float: right">
        <!-- DIV tag for fullscreen and auto slideshow play-->
        <button>full screen</button>
        <button>play slideshow</button>
      </div>
   </div>
```

I have used the classic theme provided in the downloads of Galleria.io, and which has below script to call the contents in the DIV tag ("id = galleria").

```
<script>
     $(function () {
         Galleria.run('#galleria');
       });
</script>
```

I have referrer the official documentation of Galleria for enabling [fullscreen](http://docs.galleria.io/article/127-display) and [auto slideshow](http://docs.galleria.io/article/126-slideshow).

But these documents only provide the method names, and not the example of implementing those methods. Can someone please guide how to implement these methods in script tag ?

Also, I have gone through the discussion about [auto-resize in galleria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846313/elegantly-auto-resize-galleria-jquery-slideshow-when-window-is-resized)
and tried to implement but having issues.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answers, and posting it as a reference in Galleria.io customization.
Everything will be the same, Galleria has parameters for different functionalities, that we have to call. For the functionality of auto slideshow, i edited the same script in the question this way.

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
            Galleria.run('#galleria', {     
                autoplay: 3000,
                transition: 'flash',
                transitionSpeed: 600,

            });
        });
 </script>
```